# How to encrypt entire table in PostgreSQL using key

Tags: postgresql

I created one table in posgresql database and  I want to encrypt that entire  table using key ,how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean all the data in a table. You can enable the **pgcrypto** extension.

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
```

Have a squizz at the official documentation  [pgcrypto](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgcrypto.html), to see which functions would meet your requirements.